# Deleting multiple records using foreach statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to delete multiple records using MVC. I have tried many ways. Like

```
_db.Categories.Where(p => p.CategoryID == catid)
              .ToList().ForEach(p => _db.Categories.Remove(p));
_db.SaveChanges();
```

OR

```
foreach (Category item in _db.Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryID == catid))
    _db.Categories.Remove(item);

_db.SaveChanges();
```

In both the cases only the last record has been deleted. I think the `foreach` statement is not working.

I **don't** want to use for statement (like below) which is working well:

```
if (id != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= id.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        category = _db.Categories.Find(id[i]);
        _db.Categories.Remove(category);
    }

    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any suggestion will be thankfully accepted.

Partha

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, please choose your tags properly. Tagging your question with the appropriate tags will increase the chances of someone who can help you seeing this question.

Comment: Quite normal, as in the two first codes `Where(p => p.CategoryID == catid)` (is an int probably) removes only one type of category and on the last code it removes multiple categories (id[i] change value every for / loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> foreach statement is not working

It's working. But according to your where condition you will remove only one type of category

```
    ....Where(p => p.CategoryID == catid) // I assume that catid is a scalar value like integer
```

If `id` is an array of Categories ids you want to remove, you can use `Contains` :

```
foreach (Category item in _db.Categories.Where(x => id.Contains(x.CategoryID) ).ToList())
    _db.Categories.Remove(item);

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution would be to remove a group of items using the [RemoveRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx) function. Simply select your items with linq from your DbSet, then call RemoveRange(yourItems). This way you only need to modify your dbset once, then save your context.

```
var itemsToRemove = _db.Categories.Where(p => p.CategoryID == catid);
_db.Categories.RemoveRange(itemsToRemove));
_db.SaveChanges();
```